# Find loop value inside string

Tags: c++

Check year in the title if found get the string before year e.g.testmovie, how can I do it?

```
int main()
{
    string title = "testmovie2015.mkv";
    for (int year = 2000; year <= 2018; year++)
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

Comment: You need `std::string::find` and `std::string::substr`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()   {  
char title[20] = "testmovie2015.mkv";
int year=0,i=0;
for(i=0;title[i]!='\0';i++){
if(isdigit(title[i])&&isdigit(title[i+1])&&isdigit(title[i+2])&&isdigit(title[i+3]))
{   year=1;
    break; 
}
                    }
if(year)
{
 year=((title[i]-'0')*1000)+((title[i+1]-'0')*100)+((title[i+2]-'0')*10)+(title[i+3]-'0');
 if(year>=2000&&year<=2018)
 {   int k=0;
     while(k<i)
     {   
         cout<<title[k];
         k++;
     }
 }
 else
 {
     cout<<"Year found: "<<year<<", but out of given range";
 }
}
else
{
    cout<<"No year found in the string";
}

        }
```

Comment: You're great, your idea is better than I'd like.One more question, how can I make "char title[20]" as variable, like;
string text = "testmovie2015.mkv";
char title[20] = var text;

Comment: Ok, made it, char value = "title"[20];

Comment: @ckc Great to know that! It would be really great if you could up vote and mark my answer as correct as someone down voted my answer when it clearly works. -.-

Answer (score 1):

The `string` class has two functions that are useful here: `find` and `substr`.

Together with `to_string`, you can use them like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string title = "testmovie2015.mkv";
    int y = 2015;
    std::string year = std::to_string(y);
    std::string::size_type n = title.find(year);
    if (n != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::string a = title.substr(0, n);
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: <code>#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string title = "testmovie2015.mkv";

    for(int i = 2000; i <= 2018; i++){  

    std::string year = std::to_string(i);
    std::string::size_type n = title.find(year);
    if (n != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::string a = title.substr(0, n);
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
}<code> As I mentioned on title, I want to use your code like this, but what's wrong in this code?

Comment: @ckck Your `return 0` is not in the correct place, i.e. it's inside the loop. See https://ideone.com/eaLLKE